# Finding a missing sequential number in a data file

Tags: awk, search

How can I search a large file with 'sequential numbers' (that reset after 16) in a particular column to find a missing line?

I have a data file:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 1
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 2
.
.
.
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 15
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 16
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5+1 1
```

where there last column counts from 1 to 16 then resets back to one. At this point 1 is added to column 5.

A clean output would just iterate up until the end of the file. How can I find missing data, e.g.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 1
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 3
```

where a row has been skipped/lost as can be seen from the last column that has skipped the value of 2?

I'd like the line number/location of the line before or after the missing data as the desired output.

[This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867729) gave me the idea to use `awk`. So what I've come up with is:

`awk '$6!=p+1{print NR}{p=$6}'`

To try and print the current line number when column 6 of the current line is not equal to column 6 of the last line +1. This fails due to the looping nature of getting to 16 and going back to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cat -n file
 1  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 14
 2  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 15
 3  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 16
 4  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 1
 5  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 2
 6  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 15
 7  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 16
 8  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 4
 9  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 5

$ awk '{if (p % 16 + 1 != $6) printf("line %d is bad: %s\n", NR, $0); p=$6}' file
line 1 is bad: col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 14
line 6 is bad: col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 15
line 8 is bad: col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 4
```

To understand the value of the modulo operator "%" (division remainder), you may play around with this awk snippet:

```
$ yes | head -n 40 | awk '{x=NR-1; print x, "->", x % 16}'
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
[...]
14 -> 14
15 -> 15
16 -> 0
17 -> 1
18 -> 2
[...]
```

Comment: That works like a charm. How does it work? (Specifically the `p % 16` bit)

Comment: regarding "%" google "modulo operator", it's not only awk specific: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @Christopher If you worry about `%` use `++p != $6 ... p=$6<16?$6:0}'`

Comment: @Costas This could be wrong if you have numbers >=17.  It would say 1 after 17 is correct.

Comment: Firstly 17 after any number (even after 16) is incorrect. And up to you which number after 17 is correct? 2?

Comment: But 1 can only be correct if it is either the first line or the line before is 16. Your version would print 2 after 17 but not 1 after 17. That's at least inconsistent.